# NLog JSON structred event-property

Tags: json, nlog

This is my NLog configuration:

```
<layout type="JsonLayout">
                <attribute name="businessProcessName" layout="${event-properties:rawMessage:item=BusinessProcess}" />
                <attribute name="businessDepartmentName" layout="${event-properties:rawMessage:item=BusinessDepartment}" />
                <attribute name="logType" layout="${event-properties:rawMessage:item=logType}" />
                <attribute name="queueName" layout="${event-properties:rawMessage:item=QueueName}" />
                <attribute name="data" layout="${event-properties:rawMessage:item=LogF_AllTransactionData}" />
              </layout>
```

Which is giving me the following result:

```
{ "businessProcessName": "ACME", "businessDepartmentName": "Lior", "logType": "User", "queueName": "LoggingTest", "data": "{\r\n  \"ExecuterJobGUID\": \"Studio_05fe3a0e-dc3b-4635-a521-5fe450cdb13e\",\r\n  \"LogF_TransactionReference\": \"MyTransaction\",\r\n  \"LogF_StartTransactionTime\": \"08\/02\/2022 17:11:33\",\r\n  \"LogF_TransactionId\": \"23031\",\r\n  \"LogF_QueueName\": \"LoggingTest\",\r\n  \"LogF_QueueDefinitionId\": 545,\r\n  \"LogF_SpecificContent\": {\r\n    \"FirstName\": \"Lior\",\r\n    \"LastName\": \"Hen\",\r\n    \"BirthDate\": \"1989-12-03T00:00:00Z\"\r\n  },\r\n  \"LogF_Progress\": \"\",\r\n  \"LogF_RetryNo\": 0,\r\n  \"Gender\": \"Male\",\r\n  \"City\": \"Ashdod\"\r\n}" }
```

I have two questions please:

1. How can I bring 'data' as Json and not as string?
2. How can I bring a single key from 'data', such as 'LogF_TransactionReference'?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that the LogEvent-Property contains valid JSON, then you can specify `encode="false"`:

```xml
<attribute name="data" layout="${event-properties:item=LogF_AllTransactionData}" encode="false" />
```

Then NLog will not encode/escape the LogEvent-Property-Value as JSON-string-property.

NLog [${event-properties}](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/EventProperties-Layout-Renderer) has the **objectpath**-option, but it requires that you provide the original object, instead of having serialized to JSON upfront.

```xml
<attribute name="data_id" layout="${event-properties:item=LogF_AllTransactionData:objectpath=Id}" />
<attribute name="data" layout="${event-properties:item=LogF_AllTransactionData:format=@}" encode="false" />
```

Alternative approach would be to implement [custom-layout-renderer](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-write-a-custom-layout-renderer) that parses the JSON-Object and output the wanted property. But it has a performance penalty.

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging

Comment: Hi @Rolf Kristensen , thank you for your answer!
I tried so many ways to accomplish my second wish. Unfortunately, none of them works.

This gives me a perfect JSON:
`<attribute name="data" layout="${event-properties:rawMessage:LogF_AllTransactionData" encode="false"/>`
But I just can't drill one more step down.

Comment: @liorhen9 Guess my answer is unclear. But NLog cannot dive into JSON-documents and extract values. And I provided you 2 alternatives. One is to not give JSON-document to NLog but just give the original object which the JSON comes from (and use `objectpath=`). The alternative approach is building your own custom layout-renderer than can dive into JSON-document, but it will have a huge performance penalty.

Comment: Hi @Rolf Kristensen, thanks for your details answer. I have one more question please:
It give's me a multiline json: `<attribute name="transactionAnalyticsData" layout="${event-properties:rawMessage:LogF_AllTransactionData" encode="false"/>`
how can I make it to be single-line? I tried to add `format=@` but then it turned into serialized string.

Comment: Maybe replace all newlines with white-space in the JSON-blob like this: `<attribute name="data" layout="${replace-newlines:replacement= :${event-properties:LogF_AllTransactionData}}" encode="false"/>`

Comment: Hi @Rolf Kristensen, You are awesome! Thank you :)

Comment: Hi @Rolf Kristensen, maybe you can help me with this one:
I have an attribute that I want to include only if LogLevel is at least 'Error'. I know that I need to write this:
`Layout="${when=level>=LogLevel.Error}"`
but the attribute has inner Json Layout so it ignores my condition. I assume I don't realize how to implement the condition. That's what I have now, which doesn't work:
`<attribute name="error" encode="false" Layout="${when=level>=LogLevel.Error}">
    <layout type="JsonLayout">
        <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
    </layout>
</attribute>`

Comment: @liorhen9 Tried to answer your question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73572370/193178