# NLog config - including JSON attribute based on condition

Tags: logging, nlog

I have an attribute that I want to include only if LogLevel is at least 'Error'. I know that I need to write this:

```
Layout="${when=level>=LogLevel.Error}"
```

but the attribute has inner Json Layout so it ignores my condition. I assume I don't realize how to implement the condition.
That's what I have now, which doesn't work:

```
<attribute name="error" encode="false" Layout="${when=level>=LogLevel.Error}">
    <layout type="JsonLayout">
        <attribute name="message" layout="${message}" />
    </layout>
</attribute>
```

Answer (score 2):

By default NLog JsonLayout Attributes will be ignored when not generating output for the LogEvent. So just ensure that none of the attributes produce any output, and it will "exclude" automatically.

When using nested NLog JsonLayout with `encode="false"` then must also specify `renderEmptyObject="false"`:

```xml
<attribute name="error" encode="false">
    <layout type="JsonLayout" renderEmptyObject="false">
        <attribute name="message" layout="${message:when=level>=LogLevel.Error}" />
    </layout>
</attribute>
```

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/JsonLayout

Comment: hi @Rolf Kristensen . Thank you so much, as always :)
this one:
`layout="${when=level>=LogLevel.Error:inner=${message}}"`
didn't work for me (it always renders "}")
so I used this one:
`layout="${message:when=level>=LogLevel.Error}"`